# Javascript interpreter implementation: what needs to be stored in memory?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction

I'm implementing a Javascript interpreter in a high-level language.  I haven't done this before, so I'm getting my bearings...learning about shunting-yard algorithms and basics like that.  Right now, I'm trying to rough out the implementation of functions, and I want to make sure I'm clear on what needs to be stored in memory.  It seems that the number of things one needs to remember is smaller than one might think:

- The statements (what should these look like in memory?)
- The call stack, which is a stack of open contexts.
- Each context contains: 1: Variables, and 2: A pointer to the parent context, and a copy of the statement that triggered the call, with its expressions and their current state of evaluation. 3: an indicator of whether the function was called with *new*.
- For closures, we also have variables in some closed contexts.  These are contexts that might still be needed even though they are closed, because there is still a pointer into them, in the form of a function which was created within the closed context.  (And contexts enclosing the closed ones.)
- The current statement, with its current state of evaluation.
- What statement is next.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your list sounds more or less correct. You also need to include global objects like Math, Date, etc. And speaking of which, you need to define a layout for objects too, and every value in JavaScript is an object.

Comment: I presume you've already [read the complete ES standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)? I think you can follow it quite closely with your implementation, as long as you don't care about speed or memory efficiency.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up [(Stack) Contexts](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-execution-contexts) with [(Lexical) Environments](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-lexical-environments). They should be treated as separate entities.

Comment: I never realized the ECMA standard was actually useful :)  Thanks!